# Filters move to bottom in admin grid

Tags: magento-2.1, grid, filter, sequence

I have created a custom column to filter in sales order and the filters have been move to the bottom of the page. How could I move to the top?
[image]

Comment: Is this a custom grid. Try clearing cache.

Comment: @SumitVerma it is not a custom grid, it is the order grid. I have cleaned cache and it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide your column declaration? Maybe there is something missing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to define dependency in your module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Modulename" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

disable and re enable your module and check.

Comment: I have defined the dependency, I have cleaned cache, I have run static content deploy in backend and I have even truncated the table ui_bookmark and it doesn't work.

Comment: check the sequence of your module in `app/etc/config.php` if its above the `Magento_Sales` try placing below it and check

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: Thanks. It's works. I had dependencies in my module.xml badly written.

Comment: @Priyank Thanks! I put my modules at last in config.php and that solved my problem.

Comment: @Deeps Make sure you add sequence, as I guess `config.php` generates every time when you fire `s:up` command.

Comment: @Priyank Yes, I agree with you. I've already added dependency in module.xml as above and that too worked for me. (y)

Comment: After changing module file with sequence tag you have to `s:up` then it will change `config.php` file as per sequence define in module file.I am in Magento2.3

Answer (score 4):

Please define dependencies in your module so that your module will load after the dependent one.

Add this code into your module.xml file

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Sales" />
    </sequence>
</config>
```

Please refresh the cache after this.

Comment: I have defined the dependency, I have cleaned cache, I have run static content deploy in backend and I have even truncated the table ui_bookmark and it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. It's works. I had dependencies in my module.xml badly written.

Comment: @raumatbel Can you please share how did you added dependencies in your module.xml? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @Deeps if you are adding a custom column in sales order, the dependency is the one described in the solution. Where do you want add your custom column?

Comment: @raumatbel Dependency didn't worked for me. Solution given by Priyank in above thread worked for me. I made the changes in config.php and placed my custom module after Magento_sales.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue i have faced in few day's back.
In my case there were issue with listing_top position.

```
<container name="listing_top">
    ...
    ...
</container>
<columns name="">
</columns>
```

listing_top elements should be before  elements.

First need to find all extended ui_component files from other modules.
Check in one of file having listing_top element below  elements. if it is then move before  elements like above i have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot... Ajay Gohel. You saved my time. I just placed <container name="listing_top"></container>. And that's done.